# copy and cancel int array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I got two arrays, both are sorted. One array is filled with repeating values, the other one filled with values that shall be cancelled in the first array. For example:

```
int * val = new int[11];
val[0] = 1; val[1] = 1;
val[2] = 2; val[3] = 2; val[4] = 2; val[5] = 2; 
val[6] = 3; 
val[7] = 4; 
val[8] = 5; val[9] = 5; val[10] = 5;

int * invalid = new int[2]; invalid[0] = 2; invalid[1] = 5;
```

Then the output shall be like this

```
int * valid = new int[4];
valid[0] = 1; valid[1] = 1;
valid[2] = 3; 
valid[3] = 4;
```

How can I implement this efficiently using a `for` loop? I want to point out that I do not want to switch to containers like `vector` or `list`, because I know there will be comments going in that direction. I explicitly want work with arrays.

Comment: `delete[] val` etc. is neglected for the sake of clarity

Comment: Can be used another array to store your desired value?

Comment: @BlackBird: what exactly do you mean? don't I store the desired values in another array in my example? `val` will partially be copied to `valid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should count the number of elements in the source array that satisfy the condition and then allocate enough memory for the elements.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N1 = 11;
    const size_t N2 = 2;
    int * val = new int[N1] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 };
    int * invalid = new int[N2] { 2, 5 };
    int *valid = nullptr;

    auto n = std::count_if( val, val + N1, 
                            [=]( int x ) { return !std::binary_search( invalid, invalid + N2, x ); } );

    if ( n )
    {
        valid = new int[n];

        std::copy_if( val, val + N1, valid, 
                      [=]( int x ) { return !std::binary_search( invalid, invalid + N2, x ); } );
    }

    if ( valid ) std::copy( valid, valid + n, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 1 3 4
```

You can use standard algorithm `std::binary search` if the invalid array has many elements or you can just write the lambda expression like

```
[=]( int x ) { return x != invalid[0] && x != invalid[1]; }
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N1 = 11;
    const size_t N2 = 2;
    int * val = new int[N1] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 };
    int * invalid = new int[N2] { 2, 5 };
    int *valid = nullptr;

    auto is_valid_element = [=]( int x ) { return x != invalid[0] && x != invalid[1]; };
    auto n = std::count_if( val, val + N1, is_valid_element );

    if ( n )
    {
        valid = new int[n];

        std::copy_if( val, val + N1, valid, is_valid_element );
    }

    if ( valid ) std::copy( valid, valid + n, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler should support C++ 2011.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow store the changes/deleted values? let's say I have a second array `float * val2 = new float[N1] {0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 1, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33}` and I need to cancel the values in there accordingly, such that the result `float *valid2` is of size `n` and the resulting values are `{0.5, 0.5, 1, 1}`?

Comment: @SemtexB I have not understood what is the difference between the task described in your question and the task described in the comment.

Comment: I meant that I have the arrays `val, val2, invalid, valid, valid2`. I run the code above and lets say i copy `val[pos]` into `valid[validpos]`, because `val[pos]` is not invalid, additionally I want to copy `val2[pos]` into `valid2[validpos]`. On the other hand if `val[pos2]` is invalid than I do not want to copy `val2[pos2]`.

Comment: @SemtexB You should ask a new question because what you have described differs from the original question.

Comment: I justed posted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616094/c-cancel-array-elements-and-cancel-elements-in-second-array-accordingly

Answer (score 3):

If both are sorted, this is just a simple O(N+M) algorithm: start with both arrays at zero index, and increment the one pointing to the smaller value. If you incremented the target array, copy unless it equals the invalid array.

Also, since you are only removing items, you can avoid some copies if you don't have to keep the original data: you can keep a counter how many items you discarded, and copy into the same array to `currentIdx-discardedCount` if `discardedCount` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
const int SIZE_1 = 11;
const int SIZE_2 = 2;

/*find out if item should be exclude from result array; this take linear time over the size of the invalids array*/

bool doNotInclude(int item, int invalids[], int size)
{
    bool remove = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(invalids[i] == item)
        {
            remove = true;
        }
    }
    return remove;
}

int main() {

    //array of values
    int * val = new int[SIZE_1] { 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5 };

    //values to ignore
    int * invalid = new int[SIZE_2] { 2, 5 };

    //result array
    int *valid = new int[SIZE_1];

    //keep track of result array current index/ size
    int currentIndex = 0;

    /*check if elements of input array are in invalids, if not put them in the result array*/

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_1; i++)
    {
        if(!doNotInclude(val[i], invalid, SIZE_2))
        {
            valid[currentIndex] = val[i];
            currentIndex++;
        }
    }

    //print result
    //currentIndex is now the size of the valid array
    for(int n = 0; n < currentIndex; n++)
    {
        std::cout << valid[n] << ' ';
    }

}
```

This method of doing it is O(N*M) whether the arrays are sorted or not.

Answer (score -3):

Conceptually, an algorithm like this pseudo-code:

```
int i, j;

j = 0;
for (i=0; i < length(val); i++) {
  if (val[i] != VALUE_TO_DELETE) {
    val[j++] = val[i];
  }
}
... now discard, or ignore, anything in "val" beyond element #j.
```

We simply iterate through the array, copying anything that is *not* the value we want to get rid of.  `i` is the cursor used to find values, and `j` says where to put them.

Values beyond element #`j` *are still there,* physically, but you ignore them.

---

For the sake of completeness, if we are looking for `invalid` numbers:

```
int i, j, k;
boolean delete_me;

j = 0;
for (i=0; i < length(val); i++) {

  // search the "invalid" list to see if the number is in it
  delete_me = false;
  for (k = 0; k < length(invalid); k++) {
    if (val[i] == invalid[k]) {
      delete_me = true;
      break;              // quit the loop as soon as we know ...
    }
  }

  // copy what is NOT in it
  if (!delete_me) {       // notice: "if NOT" ...
    val[j++] = val[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: `VALUE_TO_DELETE` is an array.

Comment: don't I need to iterate over `invalid`, which is your `VALUE_TO_DELETE` as well?

Comment: Yes, obviously so.  Set a boolean flag to `false`, iterate over the `invalid` list, and set it to `true` (and break out of the loop) if there's a match.  Then, apply the logic as-shown if that flag remains `false`.  *Q.E.D.*

Comment: Having a few minutes of time on my hand, I added this to the answer.

Comment: great thanks. Just a quick note. Wouldn't it also work (faster) if I start in the nested loop over `k` at the position + 1 before I break? I.e. right before break I store `pos = k+1` and then in the next round I start at `k=pos` (`for(k=pos;...){}`)

Comment: But now you wrote a O(N*M) algorithm, while this can be done in O(N+M)